# Can you run a correlation using a variable with a mixed positive and negative range?

Tags: correlation, spss

For example, if you wanted to find a correlation between smoking and weight change and your survey items ask: "How many days, in the past 30 days, have you smoked a cigarette?" (range 0 to 30) and "How many lbs have you gained or lost in the past month?" (range -30 to 30)
Is it still appropriate to run a correlation?

Comment: YES. Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225795/correlation-when-one-variable-has-both-positive-and-negative-values

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is no problem to calculate a correlation between 2 variables, taking negative or positive values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no problem. In fact, data is centered around zero as preprocessing before computing the correlation.